# DisableAddressSharing registry is not working

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp, msdn

I am trying to use DisableAddressSharing registry to disable port sharing between sockets but it's not working.
DisableAddressSharing is set to 1.

```
socket server1 = bind(INADDR_ANY,Port)
socket server2 = bind("127.0.0.1",Port)
```

If I use `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDR`in server1 socket then address sharing is disabled. Is there any reason that registry is not working ?

Comment: Where did you find that DisableAddressSharing information?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc781532(v=ws.10)) for that registry setting is quite old.  It's possible that it is no longer supported.

Comment: There is no documentation that suggest it's no longer supported.

Comment: @user2831322: on the very top it says "Windows server 2003".

Answer (score 1):

A reboot is required for this setting to take effect.

> As a workaround, Microsoft provides a registry setting that will globally (system-wide) prevent all sockets from reusing any port that is already in use. This is done by setting to 1 the "DisableAddressSharing" value of the "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Afd\Parameters" key. (Reboot required for the setting to take effect).
> The administrator should first confirm that disallowing socket reuse globally does not break the functionality/correctness of existing legitimate servers on the system. If it's safe, the setting described above should be used to apply this security measure.

Please refer to Microsoft article on SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE before implementing this feature.